# list that contains only the elements that are common between 2 imput lists (I can not do it without duplicate)

Tags: python, list-comprehension

From two lists, return a list that contains only the elements that are common between the 2 imput lists. **Without duplicates.**

Imput:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

My solution:

```
common_list = [i for i in a if i in b]
```

My output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

Output i need:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, you are right but I want to do this via list-comprehension. I just don't understand them well and trying to figure out how to correct what I wrote.

Comment: if you don't use sets you'll have O(n*2) complexity. And you can't do that with list comprehension because you need to keep track of the already existing elements.

Comment: you can use your solution, then filter out the elements whose count is not 1 using another list comprehension. Or chain 2 list comprehensions. But it's inefficient.

Comment: If you really want to use only lists, you can do this: `common_list = []; common_list.extend(i for i in a if i in b and i not in common_list)`

Comment: It was exactly what I needed! I did the same but with out: common_list = []; at the beginning and I did no have idea why it doesn't work. I'm just learning to program and I don't understand much yet. Thank you very much @GZ0

Comment: I understand using  set() is better, but  it's just for learning purpose

Comment: @BartekWęgrzyn `common_list` needs to be initialized before being used and updated during its extension.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the set operation

```
In [13]: a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
    ...: b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

In [14]: list(set(a) & set(b))
Out[14]: [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

The problem with your code is the duplicate elements in the output.. You can avoid that by applying set operator on the output

```
common_list = list(set(i for i in a if i in b))
```

Comment: `set()` can act on a generator expression. It is unnecessary to construct the inner list in the second solution.

Comment: Sure.. i agree.. i wanted to just point why the solution did not work. that was my intention :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use set intersection:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

out = list(set(a).intersection(set(b)))
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Arun's answer, you can also do this:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
set(a).intersection(b)
```

Which I find more readable than `set(a) & set(b)` because that feels a little too "magical" to me.